# Find the last visit by teacher and show the rest of columns in MySql

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to group the teachers by the last visit and show the other values corresponding to the last visit.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visits` (
`FIELD1` int(5) NOT NULL,
`teacher` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
`visit_time` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`1A` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`2A` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL  
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I used this query

```
 SELECT i1.* FROM visits AS i1 LEFT JOIN visits AS i2
ON (i1.teacher = i2.teacher AND i1.visit_time < i2.visit_time) WHERE i2.visit_time IS NULL
```

The query in general gives correct results, but in the end there are more teachers than expected (for example when using group by teacher).

Comment: Your query seems correct. It will show all teachers and their last visit. What is the issue?

Comment: It may show though more than 1 visit for teachers that have `null` in their `visit_time`.

Comment: The issue is that running the query I got different result (number of teachers; cirka 20 more) than when using group by teacher. Interesting is that when turning the < to > I got different amount of teachers too. (cirka 15 more).

Comment: When I run `SELECT * FROM visits where visit_time is null` it returns no result.

Comment: It would be easier with some sample data. The queries, as you have explained, seem to work well (the amount must vary if you change `< to >` because is a cartesian product), first try checking `SELECT i1.* FROM visits AS i1 LEFT JOIN visits AS i2 ON i1.teacher = i2.teacher`

Comment: Another reason for getting more results is that some  teachers have more than 1 row with the same (maximum) `visit_time`.

Comment: @CharlyRojasV That query returns nearly 114000 records (there should be unique cirka 12500 teachers).

Comment: @ypercube Right, there were rows with the same visit_time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join all the teacher's last `visit_time` value against the whole `visits` table

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(
    SELECT teacher,MAX(visit_time) visit_time
    FROM visits GROUP BY teacher
) A INNER JOIN visits B USING (teacher,visit_time);
```

Based on this query, you should also add the following index

```
ALTER TABLE visits ADD INDEX teacher_visit_time_ndx (teacher,visit_time);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

Is the FIELD1 supposed to be a primary key/unique column? If so, albeit it might not be the fanciest solution, you could achieve what you are trying to achieve with a subquery. I usually work with T-SQL, so I'm not 100% sure of the syntax, but I ran it through a checker so hopefully it's correct.

```
SELECT i1.* FROM visits AS i1
WHERE i1.Field1 = 
    (SELECT  i2.Field1 FROM visits AS i2
     WHERE i2.Teacher = i1.Teacher AND i2.visit_time is not null 
     LIMIT 1 
     ORDER BY i2.visit_time DESCENDING)
```

If the FIELD1 column is not a key, you could switch it out to the visit_time field. It will be slower but the result should be the same.

I am uncertain how to interpret visit_time null. Since the table is named visits there should be no rows with visit_time null, right? If they haven't visited at a point in time, they should logically not have visited at all, right?